# plot graph for visits,page view,clicks

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to plot a graph for users visits,page-view, clicks  to display in my website dashboard.How better to do this in php?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to use analytics widget like http://www.analytics7.com/  
if you already have the data, you can use HighCharts -> http://www.highcharts.com/ or dygraphs -> http://dygraphs.com/

Answer (score 0):

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

[Google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

[jQplot](http://www.jqplot.com/)

I've personally used highcharts , and its really great and well documented.